# Current cursor position in the PDF document

Tags: c#, itext

I'm having a requirement where I want to insert an image at the current cursor position of the PDF document. Will it be possible using itextSharp library? If yes, please tell me which interfaces I can use to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I insert an image with iTextSharp in an existing PDF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583629/how-can-i-insert-an-image-with-itextsharp-in-an-existing-pdf)

Comment: On, and there's no *"cursor"* in a PDF document by the way. Maybe your library maintains one for document construction simplicity, but that's all.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't clear.

**A.** If you are creating a document from scratch, you could be using...

[1.] a sequence of `document.add()` calls in which you add elements such as `Paragraph`, `PdfPTable`,...

In that case:

1. just create an `Image` object and do `document.Add(image);` in which case, the image will be added. However, not that you may want to change the image sequence default: [Image not sequentialy added in pdf document itextsharp (wrong order of elements)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22664126/image-not-sequentialy-added-in-pdf-document-itextsharp-wrong-order-of-elements)
2. if you really want the 'current position' in the `document.add()` sequence use the `GetVerticalPosition()` method as described here: [How to find current (X, Y) position in iTextSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683955/how-to-find-current-x-y-position-in-itextsharp)

[2.] methods to add objects at absolute positions. In that case, there isn't really a cursor.

**B.** If you are talking about adding content to an existing document, there is no cursor. PDF is just a bunch of characters and lines drawn at absolute positions on a page.